# include external content in a mvc3 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, include

How to include external content in a mvc3 razor ?

I want to include some external website as it is done by php include.

I will use it in a custom helper

```
@helper myHelper(){}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `<iframe>` to include an external website as part of your site if this external website doesn't provide some integration API that you could use. Another possibility if this external website doesn't depend on CSS and Javascript is to send an HTTP request to it in your controller and fetch the resulting HTML that you could embed in your partial. Of course you might need to strip the unnecessary `<head>` and `<body>` tags from the HTML that might interfere with yours.